# react hierarchy of component with parent holding state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management

I'm trying to create a React SPA for the following case:
 School
    -Student1
    -Student2
    -Student3
         -name
         -Address
             - house-number, street, city, state, country.

If I consider, School, Student, Address as react components.
School : holds/displays list of Students, which can be added, deleted.
Student: holds/displaysinformation, such as name, address, which can be modified.
Address: holds/displays address details, which can be modified.

Now, how can I do the state management here, say if user modifies address of one of the students, how can this reflect in school.

options I could think of: 
1. use Redux, but say I want to create this School as component which will be used in another react app, would I be able use redux store at component level.

2. pass the Student object to Student react component which will update this with information when modified.. mutating props.

Note: I'm new to react, excuse me something I wrote is incorrect or does not make sense.

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export default class School extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schoolName: "test school",
      students: [],
      update:false
    }
  }

  handleAddStudent = ()=>{
    let student = {
      name : "student1",
      className: "class1",
      address:{
        houseNumber :  "1-2/A-3",
        street: "street1",
        city: "city1",
        country: "country1"
      }
    }
    this.state.students.push(student);
    this.setState({ update: true});
  }

  handleToJson = () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <ul>{
        this.state.students.map((student)=>{
            return <Student student={student}/>
        })
      }
      </ul>
      <button onClick={this.handleAddStudent}>Add Student </button>
      <br/>
        <button onClick={this.handleToJson}>To json</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export class Student extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      studentName: this.props.student.name,
      className: this.props.student.className,
      address: this.props.student.address
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e)=>{
    const value = e.target.value;
    switch(e.target.name)
    {
      case 'studentName':
        this.setState({ studentName: value});
        this.props.student.name = value;
        break;
      case 'className':
        this.setState({ className: value });
        this.props.student.className = value;
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name='studentName' value={this.state.studentName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input name='className' value={this.state.className} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Address name='address' address={this.state.address}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class Address extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      houseNumber: this.props.address.houseNumber,
      street: this.props.address.street,
      city: this.props.address.city,
      country: this.props.address.country
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case 'houseNumber':
        this.setState({ houseNumber: value });
        this.props.address.houseNumber = value;
        break;
      case 'street':
        this.setState({ street: value });
        this.props.address.street = value;
        break;
      case 'city':
        this.setState({ city: value });
        this.props.address.city = value;
        break;
      case 'country':
        this.setState({ country: value });
        this.props.address.country = value;
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input name='houseNumber' value={this.state.houseNumber} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input name='street' value={this.state.street} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input name='city' value={this.state.city} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input name='country' value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you plan to reuse a component in another app entirely, you would have to give that app its own state management. As for state management options, you have the context api, passing via props and redux. Redux is likely overkill for anything that isn't a very large and complex app.

Comment: I have updated the post with code snippent, where parent supplies the Student object as props to child and child updates whenever user changes.. But I per react guidelines this is not right approach(mutating in child).... may I know details in 'you have the context api, passing via props and redux'..

Comment: I'll write an answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **using local state in React is fine**. The general rule is to lift state to a level where each component that relies on it, will have easy access to it. If the data within it only matters to that specific component, then keep it local.

> Now, how can I do the state management here, say if user modifies address of one of the students, how can this reflect in school.

Based on your use case, it would be most effective to keep a list of students and their properties inside the `<School />` component. That way you can pass it down as needed without having to worry.

I notice that you have state locally in each component, derived from its props. The more efficient thing to do is to simple create references to the props, and use those instead.

**School Component (keep as is)**

School should maintain the list of students, as well as all their sub-properties.

**Student & Address Components**

These two should always refer to their props, and call a parent method to update state.

Instead of

```
this.state = {
  studentName: this.props.student.name,
  className: this.props.student.className,
  address: this.props.student.address
}
```

just do

```
const { name, className, address } = this.props.student;
```

in any function that you need to access those variables.

You should move your `handleX` type functions into `School`, and pass it via props.

You can also skip using too many props, and just use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). For example...

```
//In parent

const ThemeContext = React.createContext('default value');

...
return (
  <SchoolContext.Provider value={this.state}>
    ...
  </SchoolContext.Provider>
)
...

//In any child
import Context from './School';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}

ChildComponent.contextType = Context;
```

Hope that clears it up, let me know if there's something you didn't understand.

Comment: If I dont maintain the local state in 'Student' and 'Address' then whenever user changes value in either student or address it does not accept or if I change the state in the parent, it would end-up re-rendering the whole school component instead of  rendering student/address which ever is changed, right?.. one more thing, if have to move 'handleX' to School then I would endup moving handleX from Student and Address  and say if there is another nested component in Address for that one as well.

Comment: And also, if I move handleX from Student to School then I would endup supplying modified 'student' objectId, field name and value in handleX method right?

Comment: @akira By default yes it would re-render child components once they depend on those props. However you could use `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare the values and prevent updates when you don't actually need to. I also think that your `handleX` function should just be to update the parent's state, to which you can pass sub-properties easily. Just clone the parent state in the children and then merge it after your changes are done.